# How word can be extracted after another word in javascript with regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

i have following code:

```
var tickettext = "This is ticketid: 1111 here are some more text";
re = /ticketid: (\d*)/
found = tickettext.match(re);
alert(found);
```

what i need is number 1111, but this message pops-up "ticketid: 1111,1111"

What is the right way to extract 1111 ?

Please help,
thanks in advance

Comment: don't use `alert()` for debugging -- it is misleading you. Use `console.log()` instead.

Comment: if you need to scrape your own website, you should rethink your design. Separate the model from the view.

Comment: @Spudley—the console in my browser shows exactly the same thing as *alert*, so I don't see how your comment is of any use. Some browsers don't have a console at all, but do have *alert*.

Comment: @RobG - fair enough, maybe `console.dir()` rather than `.log()`. My point stands though. Browsers that don't have consoles are few and far between these days (IE7? IE6? uh..... what else? I don't know about you, but I don't even support IE7, much less do early debugging work in it)

Comment: @Spudley—IE 8 doesn't have a console either. :-) It's a PITA supporting old browsers, but it's really not that hard, the worst part is testing.

Comment: @RobG - IE8 **does** have a console. That was the version they introduced it. Okay, so it's not the best browser dev tool out there, but it is there, and it does include a console. Have you never tried pressing F12 in IE8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is fine. The problem is only in the `alert`.

> If the match succeeds, the [`match`] method returns an array and updates properties of the regular expression object. The returned array has the matched text as the first item, and then one item for each capturing parenthesis that matched containing the text that was captured.

Therefore, you should look inside the array:

```
alert(found[1]);
```

This will fail, however, if there is no match, because `match` returns `null` in that case. So we need a default value as well:

```
alert((found || [])[1]);
```

One more more suggestion which would have made your problem immediately obvious from the start: **use [`console.log()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.log) instead of `alert()` for debugging.**

Comment: I don't think *alert* was the issue, but that the OP didn't realise the result was an array.

Comment: My point was that `console.log` would have made it obvious the result is an array.

Comment: In Safari at least, the console shows pretty much what an alert shows so displaying the result in the console would not necessarily have made the penny drop.

Answer (score 0):

[[M]atch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) returns an array. You want `found[1]`.

Comment: There is no `g` flag in the OP's regex. You're quoting the wrong part of the docs.

Comment: That's what I get for answering a question before coffee. I removed the quote.

Answer (score 0):

No regex way:

```
var tickettext = "This is ticketid: 1111 here are some more text",
    ticketid = tickettext.split(': ')[1].split(' ')[0];
```